# Powershell list of websites using get-website?

Tags: iis, powershell

I'm having some troubles with a basic powershell command.

If i run get-website (after enabling the webadministration snappin) and running "%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoExit -ImportSystemModules", I see a list of the 10 or so websites on my IIS 7.0 server on Server 2008 Standard (SP2, not R2). It works as expected by listing these items:

- name
- ID
- State
- Physical Path
- Bindings

But when I do:

get-website | export-csv C:\my_list.csv

I get many more items with "Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement" instead of the actual value.

When it's exported to CSV it also says "Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement" for bindings when it didn't prior (when the output was in the shell).

It's sort of halfway there...

Is there a way I can modify the one-liner so I can have a list of websites with all details without "Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement" ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

try

```
get-website | select name,id,state, physicalpath,
@{n="Bindings"; e= { ($_.bindings | select -expa collection) -join ';' }} |
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\my_list.csv
```

-edit after comment:

```
get-website | select name,id,state,physicalpath, 
@{n="Bindings"; e= { ($_.bindings | select -expa collection) -join ';' }} ,
@{n="LogFile";e={ $_.logfile | select -expa directory}}, 
@{n="attributes"; e={($_.attributes | % { $_.name + "=" + $_.value }) -join ';' }} |
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\my_list.csv
```

Comment: Brilliant. Cheers, Christian, your solution is perfect.

Comment: do you mind if I ask you one more question? I'm hoping to fix the same issue for the 'logFile' and 'attributes' fields. Is there a way I can write the same sort of 'join' statement with the ';'? I tried using the same format you provided but substituting attributes for bindings but had no luck.

Comment: Thanks again! I don't have enough of a reputation to +1 as I just joined, but your solution was perfect again. Thank you kindly.

Comment: @MikeJ Should "Hi", "Thanks" and taglines and salutations be removed from posts?
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: @Kiquenet  from post (question and answer) yes, but, IIRC ,not from comments.